# orange add-ons error Orange3-Text 0.1.9

Tags: orange

my orange version 3.3
i installed all add-ons but when i want to install Orange3-Text 0.1.9
(i have xcode and python-3.4.4-macosx10.6)

An error occurred while running a subprocess
Command failed: python -m pip install 
Orange3-Text exited with non zero status.

Show Details

```
Collecting Orange3-Text
  Using cached Orange3-Text-0.1.10.tar.gz
Collecting gensim>=0.12.3 (from Orange3-Text)
  Using cached gensim-0.12.4-cp34-cp34m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Collecting nltk (from Orange3-Text)
  Using cached nltk-3.2.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /Applications/Orange3.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from Orange3-Text)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scikit-learn in /Applications/Orange3.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from Orange3-Text)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scipy in /Applications/Orange3.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from Orange3-Text)
Collecting setuptools-git (from Orange3-Text)
  Using cached setuptools-git-1.1.tar.gz
Collecting smart-open>=1.2.1 (from gensim>=0.12.3->Orange3-Text)
  Using cached smart_open-1.3.2.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.5.0 in /Applications/Orange3.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from gensim>=0.12.3->Orange3-Text)
Collecting boto>=2.32 (from smart-open>=1.2.1->gensim>=0.12.3->Orange3-Text)
  Using cached boto-2.39.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting httpretty==0.8.10 (from smart-open>=1.2.1->gensim>=0.12.3->Orange3-Text)
  Using cached httpretty-0.8.10.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/75/kxgr97zd7kggxsp8r0v12tph0000gn/T/pip-build-a9iyny1h/httpretty/setup.py", line 86, in <module>
        version=read_version(),
      File "/private/var/folders/75/kxgr97zd7kggxsp8r0v12tph0000gn/T/pip-build-a9iyny1h/httpretty/setup.py", line 46, in read_version
        finder.visit(ast.parse(local_file('httpretty', '__init__.py')))
      File "/private/var/folders/75/kxgr97zd7kggxsp8r0v12tph0000gn/T/pip-build-a9iyny1h/httpretty/setup.py", line 78, in <lambda>
        open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), *f)).read()
      File "/Applications/Orange3.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
        return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 133: ordinal not in range(128)

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/75/kxgr97zd7kggxsp8r0v12tph0000gn/T/pip-build-a9iyny1h/httpretty
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Answer (score 1):

We are well aware of this problem and are currently trying to resolve it with authors of [smart_open](https://github.com/piskvorky/smart_open) (which we require through [gensim](https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim) - one of our dependencies). The problem occurs since [gensim cannot be installed](https://github.com/piskvorky/smart_open/issues/40) with environment variable `LC_ALL=C` which is how we install add-ons. Currently, I would suggest to install it through the terminal. On a Mac this can be done by going to Orange's installation folder and running the `pip install`:

```
cd /Applications/Orange3.app/Contents/MacOS
./pip install Orange3-Text
```

Beware that Orange3-Text is still in development and some major changes are coming through the summer. So if you encounter any issues, please report them on our [issue tracker](https://github.com/biolab/orange3-text/issues).

Comment: in orange webside i saw this
Installing add-ons
Add-ons should be installed in Orange canvas (menu Options, Add-ons...).

and i could not try manual ins... :)
thankss

Comment: I have the same problem on Windows 10 . Can someone explain How to install the addon Text manually ?